# How to increase row of a repeater as text increases?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to increase row of a repeater as text increases? I am using a repeater to display image , and image description .if image description contains more character , the text is overlapping with the other rows . how can i solve this problem?

```
    <HeaderTemplate>

     <div class="HeaderStyle">
    <div class="HeaderStyle5">Edit</div>
      <div class="HeaderStyle5">Delete</div>



      <div class="HeaderStyle1">Image</div>
     <div class="HeaderStyle2">ImageDescription</div>
     </div>
     <ul id="defaultList">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li id='item_<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>' originalId='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageId") %>' class="itemStyle">
        <div class="itemStyle">
         <div class="itemStyle4"> <asp:HyperLink ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="Edit" NavigateUrl='<%#Request.Url.AbsoluteUri+"&ImageId="+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageId") %>'></asp:HyperLink>  </div>
        <div class="itemStyle5"> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server"  
       CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageId") %>' CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SortId") %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure , you want to delete..?');" OnCommand="Calling_Delete" >Delete</asp:LinkButton>  </div>
        <div class="itemStyle1"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %> ' Height="50px" Width="50px" />  </div>

        <div><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageDesc") %> </div>


        </div>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Show us some of the code you have already? This could be any number of issues depending on surrounding elements.

Comment: What element are you using for the Description ? instead of div can't you not use span ?

Comment: final line <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageDesc") %> is displaying desc of image

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
myRepeater.Attributes["Style"] = "OVERFLOW-Y:auto;";
```

Comment: my repaeter id rptMatrixs , i am trying this in code behind rptMatrixs .Attributes["Style"] = "OVERFLOW-Y:auto;"; but giving error doesnot contain defintion for Attributes..

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338817/asp-net-setting-the-style-of-an-html-element-programatically